# Solving te system AS=TS, for A, without S inverse

Tags: linear-algebra

I have come across this, and am wondering how it works and why.

$A*S=T*S$,where $A,S,T$ are matricies

$(S^t)*(A^t)=(T*S)^t$

Why does it work, that after writing it like this, one just has to solve the system, until identity on the left side, and what your left with on the right is $A^t$?

[image: Example]

[image: Proccess]

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me for answeringmy own question, but as soon as I posted it, I realized the answer, and it is very simple.

One only views it as a series of simple Bx=c equations.

If a trained mathematician might offer a "professional" answer, I'd still be glad to hear it.